# NSolve takes very long time when lots of equalities are used. Any way to speed it up?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the intersection of a line and a shape. The shape may be built from
many smaller shapes.

The constraint function (from this question) finds the equality expression which will give the allowed value which is along the line and on a surface, but not within any two shapes. This is then passed onto 'NSolve', i.e.

```
NSolve[{x, y, z} \[Element] 
   line && (surfaceequations1 || surfaceequations2 || 
    surfaceequations3) && ! (volumeequation1 && 
     volumeequation2) && ! (volumeequation2 && 
     volumeequation3) && ! (volumeequation1 && volumeequation3), {x, 
  y, z}]
```

At the moment 'NSolve' takes forever to try to find a solution. Is there anyway I can speed it up?

---

### Longer explanation with examples:

These are my functions:

```
constraints[shapes__] := 
 And[## & @@ (Not /@ 
      Through[(RegionMember[RegionIntersection@##] & @@@ 
          Subsets[{shapes}, {2}])@#]), 
   RegionMember[RegionUnion @@ (RegionBoundary /@ {shapes})]@#] &


intersections[l_, s__] := 
 NSolve[{x, y, z} \[Element] l && constraints[s][{x, y, z}], {x, y, 
   z}]
```

Everything works great for one, two or three shapes.

```
shape1 = Cuboid[{5, 5, 1}, {6, 25, 3}];
shape2 = Cuboid[{6, 5, 1}, {21, 6, 3}];
shape3 = Cuboid[{6, 24, 1}, {21, 25, 3}];
shapes = {shape1, shape2, shape3};
line = InfiniteLine[{{5.5, 10.5, 0.5}, {5.5, 10.5, 1}}];
intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes;
intersection = DeleteDuplicates[intersection];
points = {x, y, z} /. intersection;
Graphics3D[{line, shapes, {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[points]}}]
```

But for 5 or more shapes, no luck, it hangs forever.

```
shape1 = Cuboid[{5, 5, 1}, {6, 25, 3}];
shape2 = Cuboid[{6, 5, 1}, {21, 6, 3}];
shape3 = Cuboid[{6, 24, 1}, {21, 25, 3}];
shape4 = Cuboid[{6, 6, 1}, {13, 13, 3}];
shape5 = Cuboid[{6, 17, 1}, {13, 24, 3}];
shapes = {shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, shape5};
line = InfiniteLine[{{5.5, 10.5, 0.5}, {5.5, 10.5, 1}}];
intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes;
intersection = DeleteDuplicates[intersection];
points = {x, y, z} /. intersection;
Graphics3D[{line, shapes, {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[points]}}]
```

And I actually want to do 17 shapes :/

```
shape1 = Cuboid[{5, 5, 1}, {6, 25, 3}];
shape2 = Cuboid[{6, 5, 1}, {21, 6, 3}];
shape3 = Cuboid[{6, 24, 1}, {21, 25, 3}];
shape4 = Cuboid[{6, 6, 1}, {13, 13, 3}];
shape5 = Cuboid[{6, 17, 1}, {13, 24, 3}];
shape6 = Cuboid[{14, 13, 1}, {15, 17, 3}];
shape7 = Ellipsoid[{21, 9, 2}, {5, 4, 1}];
shape8 = Cuboid[{16, 6, 1}, {21, 13, 3}];
shape9 = Ellipsoid[{21, 21, 2}, {5, 4, 1}];
shape10 = Cuboid[{16, 17, 1}, {21, 24, 3}];
shape11 = Cuboid[{21, 9, 1}, {26, 10, 3}];
shape12 = Cuboid[{21, 20, 1}, {26, 21, 3}];
shape13 = Cuboid[{21, 10, 1}, {26, 13, 3}];
shape14 = Cuboid[{21, 17, 1}, {26, 20, 3}];
shape15 = Cuboid[{26, 11, 1}, {27, 13, 3}];
shape16 = Cuboid[{27, 12, 1}, {28, 18, 3}];
shape17 = Cuboid[{26, 17, 1}, {27, 19, 3}];

line = InfiniteLine[{{5.5, 10.5, 0.5}, {5.5, 10.5, 1}}];

shapes = {shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, shape5, shape6, shape7, 
   shape8, shape9, shape10, shape11, shape12, shape13, shape14, 
   shape15, shape16, shape17};

intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes;
intersection = DeleteDuplicates[intersection]
points = {x, y, z} /. intersection;
Graphics3D[{line, shapes, {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[points]}}]
```

Comment: I would recommend finding all solutions to the sets of equations, then using the inequations to discard from that set.

Comment: So, use 'NSolve' to find the solutions, then pass those solutions to another 'NSolve' with the inequations?

Comment: I would say use `NSolve` for the first part (handling the equations), then discard using e.g. `Select` with criteria based on the region constraints. Trying to impose inequality constraints in `NSolve` proper makes for computational complexity that is best avoided when possible.